# Scala Play Json to OrderdMap

Tags: json, scala

I'm new to scala. I'm trying to convert JSON to ordered Map which should have values in insertion order. But compiler says I can convert only to Map, not to ListMap and asking me to implement an implicit Read or format.

But I wanted to know is there any way we can directly use some existing functions as we have for JSON to Map conversion? I also checked for an option in SprayJson and other, but it looks like there are no existing functions available for JSON to ordered collection.

```
 import play.api.libs.json._
 import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

object Test extends App{

 val jsonString = """{"ONE":"O", "TWO":"T", "THREE":"T", "FOUR":"F", "FIVE":"F"}"""
val jsonValue = Json.parse(jsonString).as[ListMap[String, String]]

 println("Result : " + jsonValue)
}

Expected Result ListMap(ONE -> O, TWO -> T, THREE -> T, FOUR -> F, FIVE -> F);
```

Comment: why is the value type of the ListMap is `Map[String, String]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys of the Json object is not ordered and Hence the keys, values of Json object can be retrived at any order and hence it is not guaranteed to be ordered.
Ordering is maintained only in arrays not in objects. so you will have to change the Json object to an Json array to achieve this like shown below

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val jsonString = """[{"F1":{"A" : "a"}}, {"F2":{"B" : "b"}}, {"F3":{"C" : "c"}}, {"F4":{"D" : "d"}}, {"F5":{"E" : "e"}}]"""
jsonString: String = [{"F1":{"A" : "a"}}, {"F2":{"B" : "b"}}, {"F3":{"C" : "c"}}, {"F4":{"D" : "d"}}, {"F5":{"E" : "e"}}]

scala> val list = Json.parse(jsonString).as[List[Map[String, Map[String, String]]]].flatten.foldLeft(ListMap[String,Map[String, String]]())({ case (arr,(key, value)) => arr + (key -> value)})
list: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[String,Map[String,String]] = Map(F1 -> Map(A -> a), F2 -> Map(B -> b), F3 -> Map(C -> c), F4 -> Map(D -> d), F5 -> Map(E -> e))
```

Comment: Sorry. I think I was not clear in my question. I want the results to be displayed in Insertion order.  So it should display the output as ListMap(ONE -> O, TWO -> T, THREE -> T, FOUR -> F, FIVE -> F)

Comment: the keys of the Json String is not ordered. so the keys are unordered in at the source. ordering is maintained only in arrays not in objects. so you will have to change the Json object to an Json array to achieve this.

Comment: I tried using Array instead of Objects. But still, I'm not able to read the values in insertion order.    object Test extends App{                                                                                                                                      val jsonString = """[{"F1":{"A" : "a"}}, {"F2":{"B" : "b"}}, {"F3":{"C" : "c"}}, {"F4":{"D" : "d"}}, {"F5":{"E" : "e"}}]"""
  val list = Json.parse(jsonString).as[List[Map[String, Map[String, String]]]].flatten.toMap
}

Comment: @RajashreeGr I have updated by answer with your new data try that and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I should have tried it myself:( I thought you used foldLeft as I was doing the wrong conversion when I posted the question the first time and I ignored that one.   Anyways Thanks again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146373/discussion-between-rogue-one-and-rajashree-gr).